# unable to get powershell to check through folders to find file amended in last hour

Tags: loops, date, time

pulling my hair out over this line.
the only thing I can think of is it is a formatting problem.

foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem $CompanyDir)) {

## Check if the files have been modified in the past hour

```
if ($file.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-60))
```

this seems to have a mind of its own
some times it works other times it doesn't
every time I try I get a different result
basically it searches through the folder and if there is a file amended in last hour it will zip the whole folder.
it seems to be zipping now even though there is no file amended in the past hour
earlier today it wasn't zipping but if I moved the minutes to something ridiculous like 6000 it would zip
I know this is correct because when I put it into a variable and output it, it is the time an hour before
($file.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-60))

it wasn't working at all before. I moved the folder structure to another drive and it started working. No idea why this would be the case as the folders should have the same attributes regardless of their location.
I could be way off on this  but I'm out of ideas right now so any input would be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's kinda hard to tell what's going on from the little bits you've posted here, but...
You could be more explicit about what each $file is, you might be getting things you're not interested in.
Do you mean for it to recurse through subs?
Do you want to examine every manner of file, or just the "real" files?

Get-ChildItem [[-Filter] ] [-Attributes 
     {ReadOnly | Hidden | System | 
    Directory | Archive | Device | Normal | Temporary | SparseFile | ReparsePoint | Compressed | Offline | 
    NotContentIndexed | Encrypted | IntegrityStream | NoScrubData}]

Comment: I want to check every file in the folder structure, if there is one file modified in the folder then exit the statement and proceed. I've got that working because I know it continues. What I can't understand is why I get different results running the script. It's so strange.

Comment: I think you are also checking directories, and possibly devices. I suggest you filter the results of get-childitem to only normal files. Perhaps I didn't suggest that explicitly enough.  You might also want to log the activity - print out the name of the file that triggered the compressing, for example.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I'll try that shortly. Appreciate your help.

Comment: What I can't understand is that even if it scan everything surely it should pick up a recently modified file regardless. Still doesn't explain why it would work when I minus the time to something ridiculous of say -6000 hours but won't work for -1 when I know there is a modified file within the hour in the directory. I'll give it a go and let you know how it goes. Cheers

Comment: same issue when I filtered for only files

Comment: do you log or display the name of the child item that is triggering the compression?   Maybe just print out the results of each comparison,  i.e. 
    foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem $here)) {
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-60)) {
        write-output "Yes : $($file.Name) @ $($file.LastWriteTime)"
    } else {
        write-output "  No: $($file.Name) @ $($file.LastWriteTime)"
    }
}
At least it might show which children are being mischievous